# Create an array from a string based on enclosing tags scattered throughout the string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string:

> {ListingAgent First Name}
>
> I have attached an offer for your listing, {Property Address}.

and arrays:

```
$listingAgent['fname'] = 'Bob';
$property['address'] = '123 street';
```

Somehow I need to replace {ListingAgent First Name} with the value of `$listingAgent['fname']`
and {Prperty Address} with the value of `$property['address']`

I need a way to go through the string and find all of the {ListingAgent text} and replace it based on the 'text'. It's almost like a key value pair.

I tried the following but it only echoes out the first one and I think I may be barking up the wrong tree

```
function getbetween($content,$start,$end) {
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    foreach ($r as $key => $val){
        echo $key.'='.$val.'<br/>';
    }
}

$text = $coverletter['cover_text'];
$start = '{';
$end = '}';
echo getbetween($text,$start,$end);
```

this gives me:

0= 1=ListingAgent Name}

> I have attached an offer for 2=Property Address}.
>
> My agent, 3=Agent Name} can be reached at 4=Agent Phone} or by phone
>   5=Agent Email}.
>
> I look forward to closing this deal with you.
>
> 6=Buyer First Name} 7=Buyer Last Name}

Comment: you are going to want to look into `Regular Expressions`. Specifically, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to replace the tokens with the actual values.

For example:

```
$text = $coverletter['cover_text'];
$text = str_replace("{ListingAgent First Name}", $listingAgent['fname'], $text);
$text = str_replace("{Prperty Address}", $property['address'], $text);
```

Comment: Right now I only have about 30 possible {key text} options, so i could do this. But is there a way to dynamically do it, in case new options are added later.

Comment: The simplest way to do that would be to put all the values into an associative array where the array key is the token you want to replace in the template. Then you can just iterate over the array and call `str_replace` with each key/value pair.

Comment: @SmithSmithy If you have a predefined list of strings that link the words between the `{}` characters and the name in the array, you could grab the string, then get the linked array key, and use it to replace it in the string.

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution. It took me about 15 minutes to get the list and str_replace lines built. I do not forsee a bunch of changes in the future so i am going with this. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a number of ways that you could do this... Firstly, I'm assuming that you're getting the information from a database so you would probably do better to think about using `JOIN`s and creating one array rather than having two separate arrays.

## Methods

### Manual Setup

If you have complex keys that don't follow the same pattern (assumed by the **Automated** method below) you can create an index array of the position holders and the replacements and then iterate through the lot finding and replacing all relevant data.

```
$listingAgent['fname'] = 'Bob';        //Example array
$property['address']   = '123 Strret'; //Example array

$replacements = array(
    'ListingAgent First Name' => $listingAgent['fname'],
    'Property Address'        => $property['address']
    );

foreach($replacements as $positionHolder=>$replacementText){
    $string = str_replace("{{$positionHolder}}", $replacementText, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

### Automated

It's not possible to create a fully automated function without knowing the format/values of all of your `keys` but extrapolating from the ones shown:

```
$listingAgent['fname'] => {ListingAgent First Name}
$property['address'] => {Property Address}
```

To assume that, for example, `Buyer Last Name` would look something like:

```
$buyers['blastname'] => {Buyers Buyer Last Name}
```

You could use a function like:

```
$listingAgent['fname'] = 'Bob';        //Example array
$buyers['blastname']   = 'Jones';      //Example array
$property['address']   = '123 Strret'; //Example array


function replaceStrings($matches){
    global $property;
    global $listingAgent;
    global $buyers; //Add in all relevant arrays as globals

    $matches[1][0] = strtolower($matches[1][0]);
    $matches[2]    = explode(' ', trim(strtolower($matches[2])));

    if(count($matches[2]) > 1){
        $matches[2][0] = $matches[2][0][0];
    }

    $matches[2] = implode($matches[2]);

    return ${$matches[1]}[$matches[2]];
}

$string = preg_replace_callback('/\{([^ ]+)([^}]*)\}/', 'replaceStrings', $string);

echo $string;
```

### Using `JOIN` to create one array

If you are getting data from a database and decide to go with `JOIN`s you can update your code to something like:

```
$string = "
    {fname}
    I have attached an offer for your listing, {address}.
    ";

$replacementArray = array(
    'fname'    => 'Bob',
    'address'  => '123 Street',
    );

foreach($replacementArray as $positionHolder=>$replacementText){
    $string = str_replace("{{$positionHolder}}", $replacementText, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

You would obviously, in this case, have to update your place holders in your predefined text as shown in `$string`.

You are also able to do this without using joins and just merging your other arrays together which is pretty easy to do!

## Output

Given input of:

```
$string = "{ListingAgent First Name} I have attached an offer for your listing {Buyers Buyers Last Name}, {Property Address}.";
```

The output of the above three methods (where they call `echo $string`) would all be the same:

```
Bob I have attached an offer for your listing, 123 Street.
```